# Xamarin: Bind picker selected item with FreshMvvM ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel, freshmvvm

I'm creating a form where a product status needs to be selected with a dropdown menu.
I've created a picker for this. The data is loaded from a list in my ViewModel, but it doesn't get sent back.
I've tried the same using entry fields and that works fine. I just have no idea how to link the picker with the view model.

Here's my code.

Xaml

```
    </Grid>
                    <Label Text="Current status" Style="{StaticResource MainLabel}"/>
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource MainLabel}" Text="{Binding ProductionStatus, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <!-- gets send when saved-->
                    <Entry Style="{StaticResource MainEntry}" Text="{Binding ProductionStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Text" /> 
                    <Label Text="Remark" Style="{StaticResource MainLabel} "/>
                    <!-- gets send when saved-->
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Remark}" Keyboard="Text" Style="{StaticResource MainEntry}"/>
                    <!-- Does not bind with anything.-->
                    <Picker x:Name="statusPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionOrderStatusName}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductionStatusName}"/>
                   
    
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}" Text="Save"  Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"></Button>
```

Code-behind ViewModel

```
 public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(ExecuteSaveCommand);
            }
        }
        
        private async void ExecuteSaveCommand()
        {
            int statusId = FindProductionOrderStatusId(ProductionStatus); //the production status should be the result of the selected value in the picker
            Guid id = _CurrentProductionOrder.Id;
            string remark = Remark; // value from the remark entery in the xaml
          
            await __productionOrderService.UpdateAsync(id, remark,statusId);
        }
```

Properties

```
 
        public ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus> productionOrderStatusName;
        public ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus> ProductionOrderStatusName
        {
            get { return productionOrderStatusName; }
            set
            {
                productionOrderStatusName = value;


            }
        }
        public int amount;
        public int Amount
        {
            get { return amount; }
            set
            {
                amount = value;

            }
        }

        public DateTime finishDate;
        public DateTime FinishDate
        {
            get { return finishDate; }
            set
            {
                finishDate = value;
               

            }
        }
        public int ordernumber;
        public int OrderNumber
        {
            get { return ordernumber; }
            set
            {
                ordernumber = value;
             

            }
        }

        public string remark;
        public string Remark
        {
            get { return remark; }
            set
            {
                remark = value;
              

            }
        }

        public string productionStatus;
        public string ProductionStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return productionStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                productionStatus = value;
            

            }
        }

        private string materialNumber;

        public string MaterialNumber
        {
            get { return materialNumber; }
            set
            {
                materialNumber = value;
               

            }
        }


        private string materialDescription;

        public string MaterialDescription
        {
            get { return materialDescription; }
            set
            {
                materialDescription = value;
               

            }
        }
```

Code behind loading my data

```
 public OrderViewModel()
        {
            _productionOrderStepService = new MockingProductionOrderStepService();
            _materialService = new MockingMaterialService();
            __productionOrderService = new MockingProductionOrderService();
            __productionOrderStatusService = new MockingProductionOrderStatusService();
            _seederService = new Seeder(__productionOrderService, _productionOrderStepService, __productionOrderStatusService, _materialService);
            _seederService.EnsureSeeded();
           

        }

       

        public override void Init(object initData)
        {
            _CurrentProductionOrder = initData as ProductionOrder;
            LoadItemState();
            base.Init(initData);
        }

        private void LoadItemState()
        {
            ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus> ProductionStatusName = new ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus>(__productionOrderStatusService.GetListAllAsync().Result);
            this.ProductionOrderStatusName = ProductionStatusName;
            this.materialDescription = FindMaterialDescription(_CurrentProductionOrder.MaterialId);
            this.materialNumber = FindMaterialNumber(_CurrentProductionOrder.MaterialId);
            this.productionStatus = FindProductionOrderStatus(_CurrentProductionOrder.StatusId);
            this.remark = _CurrentProductionOrder.Remark;
            this.amount=_CurrentProductionOrder.Amount;
            this.finishDate = _CurrentProductionOrder.FinishDate;
            this.ordernumber = _CurrentProductionOrder.OrderNumber;

        }
```

Thx for the help!

Comment: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}"` but there is no property `SelectedStatus` in your VM

Comment: You are right. This is because I've been messing around with a few answers I found online.
It used to be SelectedItem="{Binding Name"} because my ItemDsplayBinding is also Name. I've also tried it with SelectedItem="Binding ProductionOrderStatusName"}

Comment: if `ItemsSource` is `ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus>`, then the `SelectedItem` should be a `ProductionOrderStatus`

Comment: Hi,

Thx for the tip. I've tried this but it still passes my original status. Not the one I want to try to pass trough my picker.

For example.
The current status is "blocked". I change it in the picker to "Ongoing". But my executesavecommand still receives "blocked"

Comment: it helps if you [edit] your question to reflect the code changes you've actually made

Comment: Sorry, First time doing this :) 
Added some extra code as well where I load the data received from the previous page.
As I mentioned. If I try to change it with an entry field it works.. Just not when I try to bind it through the picker

Comment: this is still wrong - `SelectedItem="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: Changed it to what i have now.
The ```ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" ```gets its value's from the ProductionOrderStatusName. Otherwise, I have a list with no values.

Doing it like this still does not work, unfortunately..
Damn, been searching for this for 2 day's now :(

Comment: Changed it to this : ```<Picker x:Name="statusPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionOrderStatusName}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding ProductionStatusName}"/> ``` and now it passes the entire list of productionStatusNames, not the "name" I selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making this more complicated than it needs to be

```
<Picker x:Name="statusPicker" 

 // this is the List of items X to display
 ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionOrderStatusName}" 
 // this tells the picker which property of X to display to the user
 ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" 
 // this is the specific X the user has selected
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}" />
```

then in your VM

```
 public ObservableCollection<ProductionOrderStatus> ProductionOrderStatusName { get; set; }

 public ProductionOrderStatus SelectedStatus { get; set; }
```